# Thermostat to nest.com connection rate

Tags: nest-api

I'm using REST GET calls from a google script to build a temperature profile of my house during the day. The function triggers every 15min. last_connection (and the rest of the data) will sometimes be the same 3-4 calls in a row, other times can be different each time for several hours running, suggesting variable rates at which the thermostat sends data up to the server.

Does anyone know what governs the thermostat's connections to nest.com or if there is a way to force a connection in order to get an up to date profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thermostat connects to Nest's cloud under the following circumstances:

- A 'significant' even has occurred (ie the furnace turning on)
- A timeout has occurred (ie a scheduled check in appointment)

A thermostat will be considered offline if it misses its check in window, there is more detail on why that would happen in Nest's [Troubleshooting Offline Status in the Nest apps](https://nest.com/support/article/Troubleshooting-Offline-status-in-the-Nest-apps) support article.

You can force a thermostat to come online by sending a change to it, for example changing the target temperature will necessarily force the thermostat to wake up so the new value can be set, while awake the thermostat will update the cloud service with updated information. Forcing a thermostat to wake as way to get updated data from the thermostat is not recommended as you will run into an API rate limit designed to protect the battery on the thermostat. Charging rates on thermostats are rather limited, wake it too often and it will go offline for a while, annoying the user.

Rest assured, if the ambient temperature or humidity changes by a 'significant' amount, the thermostat will wake up and update the cloud service. The thresholds of what signifies a significant amount are harder to predict as they are partially determined by charging rate. If you want to know why that can vary, Nest has filed a [patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120199660) which goes into great detail.